# Динамическое создание ComboBox и присвоение к ним элементов

Tags: c#

Вот так создаю динамические ComboBox'ы по нажатию на кнопку:

```
this.Controls.Add(new ComboBox() { Location = new Point(w, z), Width = 121, Height = 21});
```

Как мделать чтобы созданным каждым комбобоксам присваивались одни и те же элементы автоматически? Через ComboBox.Items.Add не могу, т.к там требуется для определенного комбобокса. А как сделать автоматическое добавление, присвоение?

Answer (score 3):

Указывайте для каждого из них один и тот же DataSource, содержащий нужные вам элементы.

Comment: там же мне БД нужна. А простым методом как то?

Comment: в комментариях к самому вопросу самый простой способ указан.

Answer (score 1):

Не понял: почему нельзя просто

```
var cb = new ComboBox() { Location = new Point(w, z), Width = 121, Height = 21};
cb.Items.AddRange(yourItemCollectionHere);
this.Controls.Add(cb);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

В твоем случае стоит посмотреть в сторону [Control.DataBindings](http://bit.ly/YOr4jH) и [BindingSource](http://bit.ly/YOrmqE)
Приблизительно может выглядеть вот так:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.comboBox1.DataBindings.Add(
                           "Width", this.bindingSource1, "WidthProperty");
            this.comboBox1.DataBindings.Add(
                           "Height", this.bindingSource1, "HeightProperty");

            this.comboBox2.DataBindings.Add(
                          "Width", this.bindingSource1, "WidthProperty");
            this.comboBox2.DataBindings.Add(
                          "Height", this.bindingSource1, "HeightProperty");

            this.bindingSource1.DataSource = 
                          new Test1[] { new Test1{ HeightProperty = 20, 
                                                   WidthProperty = 200 }};}

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

    class Test1
    {
        public Int32 Width { get; set; }

        public Int32 Height { get; set; }
    }
}
```